# Unable to configure SQL Reporting Services to use Kerberos

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, kerberos

We are trying to enable Kerberos with our SQL Server Reporting Services reports manager website (for ex, instructions in the article "[Configure Windows Authentication on the Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-windows-authentication-on-the-report-server?view=sql-server-ver15)") without any success so far, unfortunately. What we've done up to now:

- We've used the Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server to ensure things are OK regarding our SQL Server (The SSRS DB is in the default instance, and the reports manager website is also hosted on the same server). This tool shows no errors or problems with delegation
- We've created a domain account to run the SSRS service under, and enabled delegation for it in AD
- We originally updated the SSRS configuration file's authentication types to look like this:

  [image: XML config snippet]
- Though we have also attempted the above config with only the RSWindowsKerberos node under AuthenticationTypes. I agree with J.D in the comments below - this part is confusing, as it appears to say NTLM will be picked if RSWindowsNegotiate is present, yet [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/register-a-service-principal-name-spn-for-a-report-server?view=sql-server-ver15) says to include it to enable Kerberos.
- And we've created SPNs for our domain account

Regarding SPNs, when we've tried to run SSRS under a domain account, we created SPNs using the following setspn commands:

`setspn -S HTTP/servername.abc.local abc\SsrsSvc`

`setspn -S HTTP/servername abc\SsrsSvc`

`setspn -S HTTP/reports.abc.com abc\SsrsSvc`

`setspn -S HTTP/reports abc\SsrsSvc`

Some explanation on the above: clearly, the names have been obscured, but if the company domain is "abc", the network admins have set up "abc.local" internally in AD. For the reports manager website, it's publicly accessible via reports.abc.com (ports 443 and 80 - standard http stuff here). Several of the walkthroughs regarding SPNs for SQL and SSRS linked to an article that SqlMag used to host (still viewable [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170708023758/http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-reporting-services/implement-kerberos-delegation-ssrs) on wayback machine).

The issue we're seeing is that only NTLM is being used by any browser connection, and if we force only Kerberos, we see 401s when accessing reports. (Auth headers for NTLM start with "TlR" - and we're clearly seeing that in Fiddler as we examine the requests.)

For troubleshooting, we've logged out the User Account Control attribute in the SSRS trace file, and it's 590336 (which, as far as I can tell, is fine).

Alternatively, we have also attempted to run SSRS as the Network Service account (which MS docs say won't need SPNs in this case) - but we get the same result.

I'm looking for input on what we try next, or on what we've missed.

I'd also be curious to know if the SSRS service should be listed in the Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server (in the SPN tab) - as I only see two line items - both for the SQL Server default instance itself (which both show they're OK). [This post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6772/kerberos-configuration-manager-for-sql-server/) has a screenshot showing SSRS listed there (under "Examples of the SPN validations" towards the end).

Comment: So in the books online that you linked, in the section [Resolving Kerberos Authentication Errors When Connecting to a Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-windows-authentication-on-the-report-server?view=sql-server-ver15#proxyfirewallRSWindowsNegotiate), it states "*Kerberos authentication errors are known to occur when: The report server is configured with the RSWindowsNegotiate setting*". Your configuration appears to be using that setting. I'm no expert on authentication, but that appears to *possibly* be an issue?

Comment: The books online are a little confusing too, I'll admit. They also state "*Using RSWindowsNegotiate will result in a Kerberos authentication error if you configured the Report Server service to run under a domain user account and you did not register a Service Principal Name (SPN) for the account*" which makes me believe it's ok to use both authentication types, so long as you provisioned the SPNs appropriately. Maybe providing your SPNs to the post will be helpful here.

Comment: try to see this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/configure-kerberos-powerbi-reports
and this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCH8Fa3OpQ0

it is for PBRS & tabular but it's the same. maybe it can give you an hint about what's wrong

Comment: @J.D. - Yes - agreed that it's a little confusing. When I've removed the RSWindowsNegotiate setting, I'm unable to load any reports at that point due to getting 401s from the reports manager website. Good point about providing the SPNs here - I'll do that, thanks!

Comment: It's been a while, but my notes indicate that I needed to include <RSWindowsNegotiate/> and NOT have <RSWindowsNTLM/> in the RSReportServer.config file. Have you tried that combination?

Comment: @DougDeden yes, I have tried that and unfortunately I get 401s when trying to load reports once I've removed RSWindowsNTLM. It looks like the browser tries to negotiate and get a Kerberos auth header, but fails.